# Run stored procedure from repository using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to dynamically call a stored procedures from my repository, and here is a my implementation:

```
        public void ExecProcedure(string name, Dictionary<string, string> param = null)
        {
            List<object> sqlParametesList = new List<object>();

            try
            {
                if (param != null)
                {
                    name = NormalizeProcedureName(name, param);
                    foreach (var item in param)
                    {
                        sqlParametesList.Add(new SqlParameter(item.Key, item.Value));
                    }
                }

                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(name, sqlParametesList.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error in ExecProcedure: {0}", e.Message));
            }
        }
```

There is 3 case of call `ExecProcedure()`:

1. `_repo.ExecProcedure("usp_Test");` // call without parameters
2. `_repo.ExecProcedure("usp_Test2 @id", param);` // set parameter name after procedure name and pass value as `param`
3. `_repo.ExecProcedure("usp_Test2", param);` // if passing `param` then we use method `NormalizeProcedureName()` to set parameter name after procedure name

   ```
   private string NormalizeProcedureName(string name, Dictionary<string, string> param)
   {
       if (!name.Contains("@"))
       {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           string delimiter = "";
           sb.Append(name);

           foreach (var item in param)
           {                    
               sb.Append(delimiter);
               sb.Append(" @");
               sb.Append(item.Key);
               delimiter = ",";
           }

           name = sb.ToString();
       }
       return name;
   }
   ```

What do you think about this implementations?
Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary<string, string> param`: I realize why you named it `param` and not `params`, but the real solution was to call it `parameters`.

Even worse as a name is `sqlParametesList`: it contains a typo, and the name also contains the type ("List") which is completely superfluous.

But the real problem is that a `Dictionary<string, string>` is too limited. What if you need to pass an `int` or a `datetime` for instance? You even acknowledge this by converting the `string`s to `object`s, which isn't a solution at all.

---

`NormalizeProcedureName` is a seriously bad idea. It doesn't even do what it says, and what it does can be done far simpler with a `string.join()` -- not that this would be a good idea either.

---

I don't get the point of this:

```
throw new Exception(string.Format("Error in ExecProcedure: {0}", e.Message));
```

The stack trace should tell you where the exception happened, but you throw it away to create a far simpler error message.

---

IMO it would be far better to create a custom class to hold the necessary parameter data: the parameter name, its value and its type. You then pass a list of these objects to `ExecProcedure`, and loop through the list to construct the parameters you need to pass to `ExecuteSqlCommand`, making sure to also include the correct `SqlDbType`.

Or perhaps you can simply use `SqlParameter` instead of a custom class, it depends a bit on how you've abstracted your db logic from your business logic.

---

**EDIT:** To provide some guidance, here's an example of how I handled a similar problem.

I had to call a stored proc in an Oracle DB, which required a number of parameters. So I created this class:

```
public class LogMessageParameters
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public string From { get; set; }

    public long? Code { get; set; }

    public List<OracleParameter> ToOracleParameters()
    {
        return new List<OracleParameter>
        {
            new OracleParameter("DATE", OracleDbType.Date, Date, ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("FROM", OracleDbType.VarChar, From, ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("CODE", OracleDbType.Number, Code, ParameterDirection.Input),
            new OracleParameter("ID", OracleDbType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output)
        };
    }
}
```

Now all I needed to do was assign the proper values to the properties, and pass this class to the method where I needed to use the parameters.

Is this the ideal way? Not if I had to create a dozen of these classes, no: then I'd made sure to use reflection to figure out the type of a property so I could return the proper OracleDbType, I'd have used an attribute on a property to store the parameter name, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed naming and `NormalizeProcedureName` according to comment.  Could you please explain me how can I create a custom class to hold the necessary parameter?

Comment: This class have to be Generic, right? And then add all of instance to collections and pass in my method?

Comment: @MegaTron It depends on how your program is structured, etc. I wouldn't be surprised if there are already solutions out there, though I haven't found them when I did a quick search. Experiment, refactor, etc. Perhaps you should have a class that contains all the necessary params for one particular StoredProc, and a method on that class (e.g. `ToSqlParameters`) where you return an appropriate array.