# WebApi action that updates entity using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET WebApi project. Some of controller has method `SetAsMain(int id)` that get information about people then use stored procedure update people. How can I improve it? Should I do check `people.IsMain == true` in stored procedure?

```
        public HttpResponseMessage SetAsMain(int id)
        {
            People people = repository.GetById(id);

            if (people == null)
            {
                return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, string.Format("No people with ID = {1}", id));
            }

            if (people.IsMain == true)
            {
                return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Format("{0} is already set as main", people.Houses.ToString())); 
            }

            try
            {
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters.Add("PeopleID", id.ToString());                

                repository.ExecProcedure("usp_PeopleSetMain", parameters);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, repository.GetById(id)); // some problem here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was afraid of this when I saw [your previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104306/10582): why are you using a stored proc to update this one property? Also, this seems contradictory to me: `ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.OK` -- what is it, an error or not an error?

Comment: This stored proc not only update one property its do many thing. About `ErrorMsg`: I have to create a similar method with other name. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You don't have a `people`, you have a `person`.
- Saying `if (person.IsMain == true)` is exactly equivalent to `if (person.IsMain)`

Updated code below.

```
public HttpResponseMessage SetAsMain(int id)
{
    People person = repository.GetById(id);

    if (people == null)
    {
        return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, string.Format("No people with ID = {1}", id));
    }

    if (person.IsMain)
    {
        return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Format("{0} is already set as main", person.Houses.ToString())); 
    }

    try
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("PeopleID", id.ToString());                

        repository.ExecProcedure("usp_PeopleSetMain", parameters);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, repository.GetById(id)); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I would also recommend changing the name of the repository method that returns a person from `GetById` to `GetPersonById`. As it is currently, the method name gives us no clue what's going on. I had to figure it out from context.

Comment: Thanks. A second time I want to get not the same instance of `people`, it   should return a updated data after run stored proc. but it does not work. Could you please suggest me?

Comment: Ahh. Yes. Good catch. You are getting a new instance back after it's been updated. You can ignore that part of my answer. I was wrong about that.

Comment: Yes, but it return me the same instance as I had before without changes :(. What is I doing wrong? Thx.

Comment: I don't know, but broken code is off topic per the [help].

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, Thanks. So, another question: should I do this check `person.IsMain` in stored proc or here? What do U think?

Comment: @MegaTron I think it makes sense to do the check where you do it. If it's already set to be "main", there's no sense in making another round trip to the database.

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck with working out your other issue. One thing to check for is if your sproc is actually updating the record.